# Docker-Compose file throwing yaml.scanner.ScannerError error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

This is how my docker-compose file looks

```
version: '3.3'
    services:
        frontend:
            ports:
                - 8000:8000
            build: ./frontend
        api:
            build: ./api
            ports: 
                - 8080:8080
        reverse-proxy:
            image: nginx:1.21
            depends_on: 
                - api
                - frontend
            volumes:
                - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
```

i if I run docker-compose build on the above file I am getting the following error

> ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
> found character '\t' that cannot start any token
> in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 3, column 1

I have tried changing the version as well as correcting the spaces/tabs but nothing works

Comment: do you mind checking  - https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator , if there are any tab indentation or spaces you might be having causing above problem.

Comment: Services should in parallel with version, may be that's causing the problem.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes it was intend problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of `services` and `version` should be at the same level, so your `docker-compose` file should look like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    frontend:
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        build: ./frontend
    api:
        build: ./api
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
    reverse-proxy:
        image: nginx:1.21
        depends_on: 
            - api
            - frontend
        volumes:
            - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        ports: 
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
```